# Beginner: Java is giving me an error (short code) Syntax error on token ";", , expected

Tags: java, syntax

The code works as following giving me an error (`Syntax error on token ";", , expected`) in the third line (`private String text = "a"`), which disappears when I make the following line an comment instead of code.
Also, this is meant to "encrypt" the String, and I haven't used comments, as it is only a few lines really.

```java
public class Ebook {
    private String password;
    private String text= "a";password=(char)1+(char)1;
    //                      ^ here
        
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = "";
        char a = text.charAt(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            a = (char) (text.charAt(i) + this.password.charAt((i % password.length())));
            this.text = this.text + a;
        }
        System.out.println(this.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: `password=(char)1+(char)1;` is an invalid statement for the class body. You can only have declarations (with or without initialization)

Comment: Attention: `(char)1` will **not** give you the number 1 as a character. Instead it's interpreted as the ASCII code for an unprintable character. If you intend to have the symbol "1" as character, you'll need to turn it into a character literal like `'1'`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like -

```
private String password = (char)1+(char)1;
private String text= "a";
```

Java doesn't allow to initialize again on the class.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with the lines:

```
private String password;
private String text= "a";password=(char)1+(char)1;
```

- two fields can not have the same name.
- initializing fields on the same line must be separated by comma
- type mismatch: an int can not be (automatically) converted to String

To fix all three issues in one line, you could do the following:

```
private String text= "a", password=Integer.toString((char)1+(char)1);
```

- `password` is only initialized once.
- the fields are separated by comma
- and the int `2` is converted to String

But the value of `password` should probably be the String `"11"` and not the int `2`?

```
private String text= "a", password="1"+"1";
```

Answer (score 0):

(char) 1 + (char) 1 results in an integer, which you are then trying to save into a String.  The following code would work:

```
public class Ebook{
private String password =  Integer.toString((char)1 + (char) 1);
private String text= "a";


public void setText(String text) {

    this.text="";
    char a =text.charAt(1);
    for (int i = 0; i< text.length(); i++) {
        a= (char) (text.charAt(i) + this.password.charAt((i%password.length())));
        this.text = this.text + a;
        
    }
System.out.println(this.text);
}
}
```